# WordPress - Put URL which displays all sticky posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a new theme for my blog where I checked some posts as a **Sticky** post from wp-admin and on front-end I have given some CSS to highlight those sticky post.

Now I want to give link on that highlight area which redirect to particular page having all sticky posts.

I also want to do the same for other post formats as well, like IMAGE, LINK, etc.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom wordpress template and query.

Create custom page template for each post format lists page Like for sticky posts list, create page template page-sticky.php

Inside this page add custom query with loop of posts something like below :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_format' => 'sticky', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

You can change sticky word with any post format you want. also make sure you put everything in php quote.

Comment: I just want a URL for below code!

<div class="featured-post">
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink('sticky_post') ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
</div>

Comment: IF you are doing it by above way, like page template. you just need to create new page, select template. After that give that page link anywhere in wordpress.

Comment: But I am not creating a new page. On front page while I mark any post as STICKY it will highlight at top of all posts. And I am adding CSS ELEMENT "STAR" icon for STICKY posts. NOW I WANT LINK OF THE PAGE ON THAT STAR ICON SHOWING ALL STICKY POST - WITHOUT CREATING NEW TEMPLATE.